# clickNextButton not executing properly when previously clicking on the next button

Tags: javascript, methods

I am building a survey in Qualtrics and use the method clickNextButton to automatically direct the participant to the next page with questions. I implemented the method in several following pages. Furthermore, participants are also able to click the next button themselves. The problem arises when they do so: if they click on the next button before the time limit, in the next page the method directs the participant earlier than given to the page after that one.

```
this.hideNextButton();
var that = this;
(function(){that.clickNextButton();}).delay(40);
```

For example, I set the time limit on 40 seconds on every page. On page 1, the participant manually clicks on the 'next button' after 10 seconds. What happens then is that on page 2, the participant is forwarded to page 3 after 28 seconds instead of 40. If he would have clicked on the 'next button' on page 1 after 5 seconds, he would have been forwarded on page 2 to page 3 after around 33 seconds. So it apparently depends on his click speed on page 1 when he will be directed on page 2. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the timer for automatic redirection. call respective on click method when the question is answered so it will redirect to the respective page. and also reset the timer on every page redirection.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the participant does not necessarily have to answer the question (he can also leave it blank, or if time's up he did not answer at all). So then nothing will be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the timeout if the respondent clicks the Next button themselves (delay is just a prototypejs implementation of setTimeout).  Do it something like this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
  this.hideNextButton();
  var that = this;
  var timer = setTimeout(function() { that.clickNextButton(); },4000);
  Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageSubmit(function() { clearTimeout(timer); });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment T. Gibbons. Unfortunately, it does not work for me, see my answer below.